# Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, class

Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call but class has no parameters. Below is the code:

```
class GMCategory: Codable {
let category_id : String
let prodcat_name : String?
let category_image : URL?
let sub_categories: String?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case category_id
    case prodcat_name
    case category_image
    case sub_categories
}

}
```

Calling as:

```
var category = GMCategory()
```

Getting error in calling class, please guide. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either create a custom initializer or give a default value and var initialization for each property and you'll be fine, here's how:

```
class GMCategory: Codable {
    var category_id: String = ""
    var prodcat_name: String?
    var category_image: URL?
    var sub_categories: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case category_id
        case prodcat_name
        case category_image
        case sub_categories
    }
}
var category = GMCategory()
```

A better way is to change it from `class` to `struct` and you'll get the initializer for free, like this:

```
struct GMCategory: Codable {
    let category_id: String
    let prodcat_name: String?
    let category_image: URL?
    let sub_categories: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case category_id
        case prodcat_name
        case category_image
        case sub_categories
    }
}

var category = GMCategory(category_id: <#T##String#>, prodcat_name: <#T##String?#>, category_image: <#T##URL?#>, sub_categories: <#T##String?#>)
```

Comment: It didn't worked, same error: Missing argument for parameter 'from' in call Insert 'from: <#Decoder#>'

Comment: I tried the first option because that's the pattern following in code

Comment: That can't be true. Just copy-paste this code and try again.

Comment: yes it worked, sorry I didn't saw code thoroughly. Please clear the concept also what was wrong

Comment: Check out the exact changes I made to your code to make it work and you'll realise why it was necessary.

Comment: @Frankenstein, what if i have 50 variables in single object?